# How do I make restangular promise sequential?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, restangular

I am trying to make a form with back end validation through Restangular, Angular-ui-utils but I can't figure out how to force Restangular promises to finish before continue on with the function and thus my program keep returning null values.

Here is my code

HTML:

```
...
<form> <input name="name" 
        ng-model="name" 
        ui-validate="{uniqueName: 'uniqueName($value)'}">
        Is name duplicated? {{form.name.$error.uniqueName}}</input>

</form>
...
```

Javascript:

```
...
function myCtrl($scope,Restangular) {
...
$scope.uniqueName(value) {
   var checkResult;
   Restangular.one('service').one('validate',value).get().then(function(result){
      checkResult = result;
   }
   return checkResult;
}
...
}
```

Rest Serice output are really straight forward, it's either 'false' if the name is not in the databse, and 'true' if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Since the call to validate unique name is async. You cannot implement by returning `checkResult`.

ui-validate has i think support for promise. So you return something like

```
$scope.uniqueName(value) {
   return Restangular.one('service').one('validate',value).get();
}
```

which should be a promise i believe. If you are on correct version of `ui-validate` then it should work. Check this commit https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/issues/257 which adds support for promise in the api.

Comment: I am using ui-validate from the newest angular-ui package but still the problem persist. When I swapped the code as your suggested the console doesn't log any error but the result for the check is always a success => error result are always false.

Comment: That issue 257 seem to be closed but the version that will incorporate that change haven't been published yet.